# from th8 back to th3?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm one of the billion clashers around the globe and I'm playing th8 level now, but when I link my accounts to Google it will states that if I continue and save my account will be back to th3 level.
I'm wasting nights playing this addicted games and I'm afraid if Google has an upgrade for their system my Clash of Clans accounts will be vanished, and for this situation I'm afraid continuing playing the game and later on it will back to th3 if I do continued playing.

Any solution to this clashers and maybe some of you experience this.
Willing to listen your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with the game, I would guess that your Google+ account is already linked to another Clash of Clans base. This happens if you have previously owned the game, created a base, and linked it to your Google+ account. You can only have one Clash of Clans base per Google+ account.

If this is the case, the fix is rather simple. You just need to create a second Google+ account and link the Town Hall 8 base to it.

Personally I have 3 bases that I play on. So I have 3 Google+ accounts and each one has a different Clash of Clans base on it.

**Note:** Even if you do not remember linking your Google+ account to another Clash of Clans base, this should work for you. Please let me know if it does not.